# Adding a random Guid column to a Linq to Entities query to grab random records

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lambda

I've found some articles about using the RandomView view and the GetNewID function to pull back randomized records, but they are using this method with Linq to SQL which allows Functions and Stored Procs to be used with no return value or a scalar return value. From what I understand, a Stored Proc has to been returned as one of the Entity Framework objects from my generated model. I have been able to get that to work as an object, but not returning a scalar or no return set.

What I want to do is to simply add a column to my Linq query that contains a newly generated Guid so that I can order by the new Guids and take a specific number of records randomly. Can anyone help with some sort of lambda expression or join that would enable me to do this? It seems like it should be something built into EF, but I understand that we are on EF v1.

(Please provide code in VB.net)

Comment: Do keep in mind that guids are not random - they are unique. You shouldn't rely on them providing any semblance of randomness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my VB is a little rusty, but I think this will work...

```
Dim result = 
    From myRecord in myTable _   
    Select field1, _
           field2,  _
           guidField = System.Guid.NewGuid()
```

Comment: I think it should be:

guidField = System.Guid.NewGuid()

But, thank you very much!

Comment: Right you are.  I used to be a VB6 Jedi, but then I discovered c# and went over to the dark side. :)

Comment: I'm moving to C# right now as well, but most of my code is still in VB.net as a result of my past experience.  I still think in VB, though. I'm trying to shake that. :D

Answer (score 3):

In the Select clause of your Linq query, you should be able to insert a GUID like this:

```
var result = from myRecord in myTable
    select new {
        field1 = myRecord.field1,
        field2 = myRecord.field2,
        guidField = Guid.NewGuid()
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert. How would I do that in VB.net?

Comment: `new Guid()` will always return `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.  You need to use `Guid.NewGuid()` instead.